# Can't find Python modules - queue, websocketserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

Update - 30/04/19:

Thanks xyres for helping me out. I changed the line into queue.Queue() and now I get the following errors:

```
$ python3 netgrafio1.py
2019-04-30 16:58:45,470 - DEBUG - [asyncio] - Using selector: EpollSelector
2019-04-30 16:58:45,472 - INFO - [WebSocketServer] - Starting WebSocket server on port 8080
2019-04-30 16:58:45,472 - INFO - [WebSocketServer] - Start collector server
2019-04-30 16:58:45,473 - INFO - [WebSocketServer] - Waiting for incoming data ...
2019-04-30 16:58:45,477 - INFO - [WebServer] - Listening on 5000
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/netgrafio/lib/WebServer.py", line 114, in start_server
    http_server = Thread(target=IOLoop.instance().start)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 201, in instance
    return IOLoop.current()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 265, in current
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 632, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 578, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netgrafio1.py", line 100, in <module>
    main(parse_args(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "netgrafio1.py", line 95, in main
    tcp_server = JSONServer(host, int(params.tcp_port), in_queue)
NameError: name 'JSONServer' is not defined
```

---

Update - 28/04/19:

- installed pip3, tornado, flask
- change 'Queue' to 'queue' in the script further down

New Error:

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-11-55:~/netgrafio$ python3 netgrafio1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netgrafio1.py", line 100, in <module>
    main(parse_args(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "netgrafio1.py", line 81, in main
    in_queue = queue()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

---

I'm trying to run a script, following [this](https://netgrafio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#tcpserver) link for netgrafio. Note, netgrafio1.py is my edited version attempting to fix the imports.

This is the content of netgrafio1.py:

```
import sys
import argparse
import logging
try:
    import queue
except ImportError:
    import Queue as queue

# Local packages
#from lib.TCPServer import JSONServer
from lib.WebSocketServer import WebSocketServer
from lib.WebServer import WebServer
try:
    import SocketServer as socketserver
    from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
except ImportError:
    import socketserver
    from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler



def parse_args(params):
    """ Parse cmd line arguments """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="netgrafio - visualize your network",
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    # Set parameters
    parser.add_argument("--tcp-port", action="store", type=int,
                        help="Specify TCP port to listen for JSON packets", default=8081)
    parser.add_argument("--ws-port", action="store", type=int,
                        help="Specify WebSocket port to send JSON data to", default=8080)
    parser.add_argument("--web-port", action="store", type=str,
                        help="Specify web port to server web application", default=5000)
    parser.add_argument("--host", action="store", default="127.0.0.1",
                        help="Specify host to bind socket on")
    args = parser.parse_args(params)

    return args


def main(params):
    # Global logging settings
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - [%(name)s] - %(message)s")

    # Init in queue (producer and consumer pattern)
    in_queue = Queue()

    # Set default host
    host = params.host

    # Start WebSocket server
    websocket_server = WebSocketServer(host, int(params.ws_port), in_queue)
    websocket_server.start()

    # Start Web Server
    web_server = WebServer(host, int(params.web_port))
    web_server.start()

    # Start JSON server
    tcp_server = JSONServer(host, int(params.tcp_port), in_queue)
    tcp_server.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(parse_args(sys.argv[1:]))

# EOF
```

When I run this command:

```
python netgrafio1.py -h
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netgrafio1.py", line 44, in <module>
    from lib.WebSocketServer import WebSocketServer
  File "/home/ubuntu/netgrafio/lib/WebSocketServer.py", line 54, in <module>
    from queue import Queue
```

When I run this command:

```
python3 netgrafio1.py
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netgrafio1.py", line 44, in <module>
    from lib.WebSocketServer import WebSocketServer
  File "/home/ubuntu/netgrafio/lib/WebSocketServer.py", line 46, in <module>
    import tornado.web
ImportError: No module named 'tornado'
```

Do note that I do have tornado installed:

```
pip list | grep tor
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
tornado        5.1.1
```

I am trying to get netgrafio running, so that I get this:

```
$ python netgrafio.py -h
usage: netgrafio.py [-h] [--tcp-port TCP_PORT] [--ws-port WS_PORT]
                    [--web-port WEB_PORT] [--host HOST]

netgrafio - visualize your network

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --tcp-port TCP_PORT  Specify TCP port to listen for JSON packets (default:
                       8081)
  --ws-port WS_PORT    Specify WebSocket port to send JSON data to (default:
                       8080)
  --web-port WEB_PORT  Specify web port to server web application (default:
                       5000)
  --host HOST          Specify host to bind socket on (default: 127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: can you try "pip3 install tornado" and then run the script?

Comment: Done, then I had to update pip3 and install flask with pip3 as it was needed. I'll post my new error as well.

Comment: @xpewpewx I've updated my answer according to the new error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems OP doesn't have basic knowledge of Python and wants others to fix every error they're encountering.

Comment: Fair point, let me try and resolve this. Let's not close this just yet.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `python ...` command, your OS is probably running Python 2.7. And in Python 2.7, there is no `queue` module. In v2.7 it was called `Queue`. It was renamed to `queue` in v3.

And when you run `python3 ...`, your OS is running Python 3.x. Even though this version has the `queue` module, but you haven't installed Tornado for Python 3.

To fix this, install Tornado for Python 3:

```
pip3 install tornado
```

Then run your script using `python3 ...` command.

---

**UPDATE** related to new error.

`queue` is not a callable object; it's a module (i.e. a python file). Please see the docs for the [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) module. You need to use `queue.Queue` in your code.

```
in_queue = queue.Queue()
```

Comment: @xpewpewx The new error says that `JSONServer` is not defined. I think that is very clear. Please don't expect people to debug all of your code for you: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. It is all basic Python. If you don't that, please spend some time learning the language.